# SKPayment paymentWithProductIdentifier Deprecated. Alternatives?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

All the tutorials for In App purchases use the deprecated method "paymentWithProductIdentifier" of the SKPayments class. Any alternatives to this?

Answer (score 22):

Yes, use `+paymentWithProduct:`.

Comment: It will be more better to have convert function for so popular question an answer.